# SQL: Selecting sum of two columns across multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
-------------------------------------
|  Country  |  Count 1  |  Count 2  |
-------------------------------------
|  USA      |  10       |  10       |
-------------------------------------
|  USA      |  10       |   10      |
-------------------------------------
|  France   |  200      |  200      |
-------------------------------------
|  USA      |  10       |  10       |
-------------------------------------
|  France   |  100      |  100      |
-------------------------------------
```

I would like to select the total of Count 1 and Count 2 for each country.
So my output would be like

```
-------------------------
|  Country  |  Count    | 
-------------------------
|  USA      |    60     | 
-------------------------
|  France   |   600     |
-------------------------
```

Comment: How did you get the numbers in your output from the numbers in your sample input?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I didn't :)

Comment: Where does the source table come from? Perhaps there's an unnecessary intermediate step here?

Comment: @Stromgren You'll get better assistance if you provide the correct output required based on the sample input instead of random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

```
SELECT Country,
 SUM(`Count 1` + `Count 2`) AS count
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight-forward, you can use the aggregate function [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT country, 
  sum(count1 + count2) as Total
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY country;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ef0e/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Country, SUM(Count_1 + Count_2)
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Country
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE power 
  SET cnt = SUM(IFNULL(is_yellow, 0) + 
  IFNULL(is_green, 0) +  IFNULL(is_blue, 0));
```